# Python: how to read .py (config) file containing multiple nested dictionaries, modify, then save updated content to .py?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a following python config file with multiple nested dictionary:

```
# sample_config.py
import numpy as np
import datetime

params1 = {key1: {key2: val1,
                  key3: val2}}

params2 = {key4: datetime(2018, 3, 14)}

params3 = {key5: np.linspace(0, 1, 21)}
```

I have a main python file that calls the sample_config.py, uses the params dictionaries and update the params dictionaries.

```
# main.py
config = __import__('sample_config')
params1 = config.params1
params2 = config.params2
params3 = config.params3

test_out = test_function(input1, input2, params1)

params1['key1'] = updated_value
```

etc etc

What I'd like to do is to update the sample_config.py (or create a new config .py file) with the updated params dictionaries in main.py.

In my searches past couple of hours, many people recommend using json file, but since config file uses python modules, I'd like to keep it in the same .py format if possible..

Any help will be really appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you need to use python file? Maybe you can change it to json?

Comment: @GrzegorzBokota yes unless the overhead is terrible and doesn't justify the use of python file

Answer (score 0):

You could cast the whole dictionary as a string and then write it to a .py file. Here's an example of what I mean:

```
updated_params_1 = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
updated_params_2 = {'d':4, 'e':5, 'f':6}
new_python_file_contents = ('''
    new_params_1 = {0}
    new_params_2 = {1}
'''.format(updated_params_1, updated_params_2))
with open('updated_params.py', 'w') as f:
    f.write(new_python_file_contents)
```

Comment: thanks. however, the config py file can have many dictionaries though. I don't think your method scales.

Comment: If you're working with a large number of dictionaries, you're definitely right. But I've updated my original post to show how this could work with more than 1, at least.